# What's the equivalent of $in (in mongodb) for Elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, I have this code that matches a thread and a query. It currently works fine for matching one thread, but I have an array of threads. And I want to get a hit if the field "thread" matches any of the threads in the array. For example, if I have an array of ['1', '2', '3'], I want to match if the "thread" field matches '1', '2', or '3', not just '1'. How do I do this?

```
client.search({
    index: 'searchable-message',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              match: {
                thread: '1' //<--WORKS FOR ONE, BUT NOT  ARRAY
              }
            },
            {
              multi_match: {
                query: req.query.q,
                fields: ['message_text', 'stripped_text', 'links', 'documents.text_contents']
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to use a different query method called `terms`.

Try changing you `match` query with a `terms` query. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) is the terms queries documentation.

Example:

```
{
   "terms": { 
       "thread": ['1', '2', '3'] 
   }
}
```

The `bool` query [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) also provides a nice example of the `term` query, which has a similar syntax with the `terms` query:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term" : { "tag" : "tech" }
        },
        "must_not" : {
            "range" : {
                "age" : { "from" : 10, "to" : 20 }
            }
        },
        "should" : [
            {
                "term" : { "tag" : "wow" }
            },
            {
                "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)